# How do I effectively use "%s" as a place holder in a Database query string?

Tags: python

Here is my example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pymssql
import datetime
import time
import requests

def liststeps(date1, jobid):
    sqlquery = """
    select stepi, stepn, pckg, runst, rundur
    from src_table
    where run_date = %s
    and job_id = '%s'

    df = pd.read_sql(sqlquery%(date1,jobid), conn)
    print(df)
```

When I try to run the following python function I don't get any errors but I get the wrong output which is as follows

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [stepi, stepn, pckg, runst, rundur]
Index: []

Note, when I remove the single quotes around the jobid, i get an error "Incorrect syntax near... (part of string of data being passed)"

I am using SQL Server and I have imported pymssql and all necessary libraries.
Also, "src_table" is an alias for the actual table path which should not be needed to answer my question.

Will appreciate any help to point me in the right direction.  Thx!

Tried researching about f-strings and tried using {} for the place holders but of no avail.
I know "?" is used for odbc but I'm using pymssql.

Comment: Typically, these placeholders are *identical* to the placeholders used by `str.__mod__`, but are not meant to be used with it. Instead, you SQL library uses the same syntax for its own `execute` method that *safely* constructs a query using proper quoting, for example `c.execute("select a from be where foo=%s", ("bar",))`, *not* `c.execute("select a from b where foo=%s" % ("bar",))`

Comment: Your string literal for the SQL query isn't closed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So are you saying I can only use the cursor.execute(query, (date1, jobid)) statement and can't use the dataframe statement/format I shared above?  Sorry, not clear as to what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

`pd.read_sql`, like other safe SQL library methods, will replace `%s` with properly quoted arguments itself, rather than you doing so with `str.__mod__`.

```
df = pd.read_sql(sqlquery, conn, params=(date1, jobid))
```

Which syntax is appropriate for `sqlquery`, as well as what value to pass as the `params` argument, depends on what driver you are actually using.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm using pymssql.  DB is SQL Server.  Still not able to get the %s to work.